# Insert large text file in MySQL using Python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I have a big text file which contains comma separeted data. But inside the file, there are multiple data chunks separeted by tags  and . 
I need to insert these chunks in different tables in mySQL.

I'm reading the file line by line. 
When  is found, I 'create if not exists' a new table and start inserting line by line.

But this is taking a lot of time as the file has around 1M rows.

Is there a better way to speedup the inserting process?

Below is the code I'm using

```
    with open(file_name_with_path) as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file,delimiter=',')
    line_count = 0
    start_count = 0
    new_file = False
    file_end = False
    ignore_line = False
    record_list = []
    file_name = ''

    temp_data = []

    for row in csv_reader:
        ignore_line = False
        if row[0].find('<START>') ==0:
            file_name = row[1]
            line_count = 0
            new_file = True
            ignore_line = True
        if row[0].find('<END>') == 0:
            file_end = True
            record_list.append(file_name + '_' + str(line_count))
            line_count = 0
            ignore_line = True
            print('End of a file.')
        if new_file == True:
            print('Start of a new file.')
            new_file = False
        if line_count == 0 and ignore_line is False and new_file is False:
            line_count += 1
            create_table(file_name,row)
            temp_data.append(row)
        elif ignore_line == False:
            line_count += 1
            add_data(file_name, row)
            temp_data.append(row)
    print(f'Processed the file - {",".join(record_list)}' )
```

Sample text file.

```
<START> File1
col1,col2,col3
1,A,B 
2,C,D
<END>
<START> File2
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
1,A,B,1,2 
2,C,D,3,4
<END>
```

Comment: Try doing a bulk insert in batches

Comment: Thanks. Actually I tried this, but still for 50K records also, it was taking some 20-30 mins.

Comment: Try optimizing your code to reduce latency like removing the create if not exists ,by setting a Boolean variable so that db calls are limited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't show us the code you're running.

You suggested that, optimistically, you're getting
app-level throughput of around 40 row / sec (50k / 1200),
which we all agree is "low".
You should be able to easily achieve
one or two orders of magnitude better performance.

It's not clear if you're using a local or remote instance.
Possibly you're doing 40 commits per second to local disk.
Or possibly you're managing 40 WAN round-trip messages per second.

What you want to be using is `.executemany()` with a batch size
of about ten thousand rows inserted per COMMIT.
That would be about a hundred COMMITs for your million rows.

Numerous examples are available on the web, e.g.
https://pynative.com/python-mysql-insert-data-into-database-table/

Comment: I have updated my question with code and sample text file. I'm now trying with .executemany(). Thanks for the link.

Comment: Thanks a ton. I tried with a batch size of 1000 and now its working fine. Finishing all 500K rows in less than 2 mins on local mySQL instance.

Comment: Just one question, what can be the size of the batch? (I understand it depends on data.)

Comment: When choosing batch size, a reasonable target is to do an RDBMS commit about once a second, certainly more often than once every ten seconds. If there's 50ms or 100ms of overhead at that frequency, it won't kill performance.